# Java library to create cabinet files on Unix?

Tags: java

Is there a Java library to create cabinet files on Unix. I don't need any compression support. I just want to create a plain cab file using Java.

Something similar to cablib (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cablib/) which can only be used for reading cab files would be perfect.

If there is really no library can I use a feasible work around? E.g. create a ZIP file and somehow convert it into a CAB file?

Comment: The [lcab](http://packages.debian.org/sid/lcab) tool claims to be able to create MS Cabinet files.

Comment: Yes I was going to say that too. It's not a Java library, but if you can afford an exec call, that command would make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is really no library can I use a feasible work around?

Comments have suggested using the Linux [Icab](http://packages.debian.org/sid/lcab) tool.

> E.g. create a ZIP file and somehow convert it into a CAB file?

The ZIP file format is different in too many respects for there to be a simple transformation to turn a ZIP file into a CAB file.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The answer below isn't a pure java solution.  Ant's CAB task documentation says it relies on a 3rd-party tool: Either MS's "CABARC" or the open-source "libcabinet", which seems to no longer exist.  So there is no benefit to this approach compared to a 3rd-party system call.

### Previous Answer (read above first):

If you need a pure java way of creating cab files (not extracting them), you can use [ant's built-in "cab" task.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/cab.html)

This gives you a few options:

1. Call the ant task from within your java code by using [ant's
   Launcher class](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava);
2. Find the source code for the task definition ([here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/Cab.java)) , and remove references to the ant context to create your own Cab extract utility
3. Run ant via a system call.